# relative links work when accessing folder but not domain that references folder

Tags: php, html, apache, url, domain-name

I have a domain example.com that has a folder in it example.com/folder/ that has another domain that points directly to it so example2.com points to example.com/folder/

When I access this via example.com/folder/ everything works fine and I can access my css and js folders which are a level below the folder in example.com/css/ and example.com/js/

When accessing from example2.com I don't see the css or js on the site and I get a 404 when trying to link directly to them by clicking the link in the view source output in firefox.

I should also mention that I have no problem with PHP includes that come from below the folder example2.com points to, just with the relative URLs referenced in the HTML.

Any idea how to get the site to let me access these folders below the root of example2.com from both example1.com/folder/ and example2.com?

I'm using a LAMP system. Also, my goal is to keep the system flexible enough that I can use it in multiple sets of domain/subdomain without having to edit server files or PHP.

EDIT - I "solved" this by adding a field in my db for the root domain all the subdomains will stem from and making static URLs for the linked js and css. This doesn't seem like the most elegant way to deal with it but it's the best I can think up right now. If anyone has any better let me know!

Comment: have you tried mode rewrite with .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but sounds like [`<base href=>`](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/base/) is needed.

In your case:

```
 <base href="http://example1.com/folder/_">
```

That will make all relative URLs request resources from example1, even if users come visit on your example2.com vhost. Though all links will then also redirect people there. It affects both JS/IMGs and clicky things.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have described you folder organisation looks like this:

```
    /path/to/domain/folder/
                   /css/   ^
                    ^      |
                    |      domain2.com
                    domain.com
```

PHP on `domain2.com` won't have a problem accessing `../css` because it operates on the server, but a browser can't go further back then `/path/to/domain/folder/`.

I would suggest to create a symbolic link (if possible) on the server:

```
ln -s /path/to/domain/css /path/to/domain/folder/css
```

Alternatively, you could use `Alias` in Apache to set up aliases for `domain2.com/css` to `/path/to/domain/css/`

Lastly, a `<base>` tag could help you (as mentioned by mario), but any links followed from a page with such a tag will switch back to `domain1``.

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess I forgot to mention that I'm trying to do this in such a way that I can pick up the system and use it on a different set of domain/subdomain combos without having to edit the php, or htaccess files. I think what I'm going to do is put a field in the db for the primary domain and then construct the URLs of the css and js files as absolute URLs based on that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep the system as flexible as I wanted it I decided to put both the example1 url into the database and the folder name so I can construct absolute links to the files I need to access in the HTML page. This also seems necessary with my mod_rewrite, which changes tries to tack the locations of these files to the end of the "pretty URL" (like example2/post/2/css/main.css). Thanks for your ideas you steered me in the right direction!